# Specify the solution printed in OR-Tools

Tags: python, constraints, scheduling, constraint-programming, or-tools

When I get the solution below for example in a shift scheduling sat problem how can i specify the solution I want to print with SolveWithSolutionCallback method?

```
Solution 13, time = 37.58 s, objective = 82
Solution 14, time = 37.71 s, objective = 81
Solution 15, time = 37.87 s, objective = 80
Solution 16, time = 37.96 s, objective = 76
```

Let's say i want to see what solution 13 and 14 produced, is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Not sure how that list could be passed in the method, i tried replacing the printer_solution  variable with a list but didnt work, but maybe im doing something wrong, can you elaborate pls?

Comment: hello! please can you edit these amazing details into your post? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can store solutions in a list in the callback or log them to a file, etc:

```py
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model


class Callback(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):

    def __init__(self, variables):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self.variables = variables
        self.solutions = []

    def on_solution_callback(self):
        self.solutions.append([self.Value(v) for v in self.variables])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    num_vals = 3
    x = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals - 1, "x")
    y = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals - 1, "y")
    z = model.NewIntVar(0, num_vals - 1, "z")

    model.Add(x != y)

    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    callback = Callback([x, y, z])
    solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, callback)
    print(callback.solutions)
```

Comment: This cannot be done when you have an objective to minimize.

Comment: Search for all solutions is only defined on satisfiability problems